# How can i pass data between components?

Tags: reactjs, api, react-router

I am using React Router and now i am stuck trying to send data from a component to another (Home component and ListScreen component)

I need to send a object provided by an API and created in Home component to the ListScreen component in order to continue doing the queries based in this object.

That is the HOME component

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"
import { Link, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom"
import axios from "axios"

function Home() {

    const navigate = useNavigate()

    const [login, set_login] = useState({
        login_email: "",
        login_pwd: ""
    })

    const [error, set_error] = useState(false)

    const ChangeEmailHandler = (event) => {
        set_login({
            ...login,
            login_email: event.target.value
        })
    }

    const ChangePwdHandler = (event) => {
        set_login({
            ...login,
            login_pwd: event.target.value
        })
    }

    const SubmitHandler = (event) => {

        event.preventDefault()

        if(login.login_email.length < 1 || login.login_pwd.length < 4) {
            set_error(true)
        } else {
            axios.get(`https://localhost:7281/${login.login_email}/${login.login_pwd}`)
            .then(response => {
            console.log(response.status)

            if(response.status == 200) {
                navigate('/todo-list')
            }
        })
        }
    }
    return(
        <div className="wrapper teste screen home_container">
     
            <form onSubmit={SubmitHandler} className="login_section">

                <div className="my_labels email">
                <label id="email_label">Email</label>
                <input type="email" onChange={ChangeEmailHandler} placeholder="example@hotmail.com" name="" id="email" />
                </div>

                <div className="my_labels pwd">
                <label>Password</label>
                <input type="password" onChange={ChangePwdHandler} placeholder="At least 4 characters" name="" id="pwd" />
                </div>

                <div>
                    <button type="submit">Login</button>
                </div>
            </form>
       </div>
}`
```

I don't have content in ListScreen yet. I really need the data first to make this component works
`

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do exactly.
However, if you want to send data to another element in your current code, there are several ways.

1. When moving a page, data can be sent as follows.
   `navigate('/todo-list', { state: response.data });`
2. Using state management.
   (redux, jotai, context provider, react-query, swr, etc.)